# Multiprocessing slots in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

After looking over Thread/Queue model, I would like to ask how to create something in a similar fashion:

I have, for example, 100 items that need processing, but I want to process them 20 at a time - so there are 20 slots, and once each slot is emptied ( item finished processing ) next one would be seated and started processing.

The limit doesn't need to be 20, it could be adjusted ( 30, 50 etc) ?

Thank you for your suggestions and answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def process(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = range(100)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(process, jobs):
        print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```